# Menu_slug used for creating options page

Tags: plugin-development, admin-menu, options

I am following this page on designing options menus:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus

What is the significance of the **menu_slug** ?

I ask because when I change this value, the options page changes to

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

If I change it back to what it was, it's fine.

**---EDIT---15/8/2011**

This is the code I was changing:

```
function highlighter_menu_() {
    add_options_page('Highlighter pen options', 'Highlighter Pen', 'manage_options', 'my-unique-identifier', 'highlighter_plugin_options');
}
```

and changed it to

```
function highlighter_menu_() {
    add_options_page('Highlighter pen options', 'Highlighter Pen', 'manage_options', 'a-unique-identifier', 'highlighter_plugin_options');
}
```

Comment: The menu slug also refers to the query var used in the URL to view your given page, when you change the slug - the page you are viewing is no longer to a valid URL(because you've essentially changed it when setting a new menu slug).

Comment: also are you sure you are changing the menu slug and not the `$capability`?

Comment: Oh yes good point, i could possibly be wrong with my comment. If you are changing the capability requirement by mistake that would indeed be the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. I was making changes to the plug-in code and transferring it directly (via ftp). 
I forgot to **deactivate** and **activate** the plug-in. Doh!